# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError while trying to load applet using RXTXcomm jar

Tags: java, jar, applet, serial-port, rxtx

I created an applet using `RXTXComm.jar` to read values from a COM port. When I run the applet in the Eclipse IDE as an applet, it's working. But when I run it through my application it's giving this error in the applet console:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "Thread-17" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at comPortListen.run(comPortListen.java:65)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied                                                                             (java.lang.RuntimePermission loadLibrary.rxtxSerial)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkLink(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:83)
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your getting boxed by the Sandbox

[Security and Permissions](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/appA.html)

Possible Duplicate Thread: [Java Applet with RXTX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504390/java-applet-with-rxtx-components-for-serial-communication)

Comment: Thanks for Reply mike but after changed my code for initialization of my jar inside doprivileged method i'm getting the same error this time I changed my java policy as well (given All permission) no use. What shall I do, i'm stuck  with this for the past three days. could you help me out.

Comment: If required I can attach my code but as I'm new to stack Exchange I don't know where to add my code here. Its giving only to add comment.

Comment: Found another Sample Page for you: http://www.walking-productions.com/jsserial/new/JSSerial.html

Comment: Another more detailed page: http://vamsinotes.blogspot.com/2010/06/java-web-start.html

Comment: Thanks for useful suggestions mike, I created new java policy and given privilege and set environment variable path for RXTXSerial.dll and its working now. But now I'm facing different problem as I kept my class and rxtxcomm.jar and used in jsp under web folder of my project  as a initial level development. now if I move anywhere inside web folder its throwing java.lang.classnotfoundexception following my class name

Comment: for example I created read/com folder under web folder and I moved the "myclass.class" file and "RXTXcomm.jar" file inside this folder and I'm having read.jsp inside the same folder and used applet tag to call is                   <applet name="myclass.class" archive="RXTXcomm.jar" width="100" height="30"> </applet>.  why this is happening can you help me.